# Is there a way to catch undefined globals in PHP, and provide a value, like autoload, but for variables?

Tags: php, autoload, global

We have a lot of existing code that, rather than creating an instance of a class, or using a static function on that class, will call the method on a global singleton of that class.

For example (stringclass.php):

```
class String {
   function endsWith($str, $search) { 
      return substr($str, -strlen($search)) == $search;
   }
}
$STRING_OBJECT = new String();
```

then it will use this in the following way:

```
include_once("stringclass.php");
if ($STRING_OBJECT->endsWith("Something", "thing")) {
   echo "It's there\n";
}
```

I realise that this is not a very sensible way of calling the function, but I was wondering if we could fix all the places where people have forgotten to include the right classes using an auto-loader, without changing all the code that uses these singletons. It would detect the use of an undeclared global, and include the correct class file based on the name of the global that was being referenced.

Comment: I'd use a custom [error handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) to catch the missing objects.

Comment: That sounds a good idea, but I can't see a way to retry the object access after loading the object. Do you know of any other approach?

Comment: Well, you can try to be clever in the error handler. You will have enough information to read out the affected line, and re-execute the failed statement inside the error handler. Your options are limited, though. After all, what you are trying to do is to handle an error. You aren't fixing the issue that causes the error in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ArrayAccess interface

http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php

```
class Ztring implements arrayaccess
{
    private $container = array ();

    public function offsetSet ($offset, $value)
    {
        $this->container[$offset] = $value;
    }

    public function offsetGet ($offset)
    {
        // exception
        if ($offset == 'something')
        {
            return 'works!';
        }

        return $this->container[$offset];
    }

    public function offsetExists ($offset)
    {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetUnset ($offset)
    {
        unset ($this->container[$offset]);
    }
}


$x = new Ztring ();

$x['zzz'] = 'whatever';
echo $x['zzz']."\n";

echo $x['something']."\n";
```

Comment: That's quite nice, but doesn't work for globals. I can't just do `$FOO`, I'd have to say `$x['FOO']` wont I?